# 'filetype plugin indent on' breaks indention

Tags: indentation, filetype-javascript

Using vim 8.*, I am using these plugins:
html5.vim
polymer-ide.vim
supertab
vim-javascript

In my vimrc.local file if I enable `filetype plugin indent on` it breaks my javaScript indention but makes the highlighting correct. However, if I remove that line then my indention works as it should for javaScript but the highlighting breaks.

How can I have both the highlighting and indention working?

Comment: What do you mean vimrc.local file? Are you using some kind of distribution, or vanilla vim? If the plugins are structured correctly, turning indent on should be fine. Highlighting is controlled by the `syntax` command. Wdym by indentation/highlighting breaks/is correct ?

Comment: Until the question has more detail, I’m voting to close it as unclear. Try debugging your vimrc, and eliminating plugins, and see if you can narrow down on the details of your problem.

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/10604

Answer (score 1):

What if you just enable the filetype plugin?

```
filetype plugin on
```